# Full GC when many objects age>=15 but not long-lived objects?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

My java applications frequently use **full GC**.

By analyzing gc log, I found that there were many objects with age >= 15. I guess that many objects were promoted to the old age after reaching maxtenuringthreshold=15, which led to the tenured generation becoming larger and larger. Finally, **full GC** occurred.

But with the help of `gceasy` tool, I found that the old generation also recycled a lot of garbage through full GC. About 2390 -> 800.

What is the reason? Is it because there are many objects with age > 15 that do not belong to the tenured generation? Maybe their age =16,17,18? But not long-live objects?

Here is my JVM configuration:

```
-Xmx6g
-Xms6g
-XX:NewRatio=1
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15
-XX:+ParallelRefProcEnabled
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:MetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-Xloggc:/export/Logs/gc.log
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
-XX:SurvivorRatio=4
```

[Age distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVRHw.png)

[Old generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN8a0.png)

[Avg promotion rate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJWSd.png)

In this case, how can I tune the JVM?

Thank you!

Comment: Your `-XX:NewRatio=1` makes the New Gen smaller, potentially forcing earlier promotion, regardless of the `MaxTenuringThreshold`. Besides that, when you deliberately select a concurrent collector, you *want* to have old objects, as otherwise, you don’t have concurrent collections at all. What you don’t want to have, is a *full* old generation, as that would cause a nonconcurrent full GC. Such a scenario would be the result of `NewRatio`, `CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction`, and application allocation rate. But the simplest alternative is to drop all these options and try G1GC instead of CMS.

Comment: Have to correct myself. The `NewRatio` is not the problem, but the “Desired Survivor Size” which may cause earlier promotion here, regardless of the `MaxTenuringThreshold`. But the conclusion doesn’t change, give G1GC a try, first without any options, to see how its self-tuning performs.

Comment: It did get better! thank you, Holger

Comment: What java version are you using? You should really upgrade if you still use CMS: https://dzone.com/articles/cms-deprecated-next-steps

Comment: @JurajMartinka Java 8

Comment: You will get lots of benefits by upgrading to recent JDK versions - I recommend going straight to JDK 17, or at least 11.